# How to evaluate if a group of rows contains a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to evaluate if a *id* contains a specific *value* ('b'). The problem is, that the *id* can occur multiple times (rows). But if id '1' in row 1 contains 'a' and the id '1' in row '2' contains 'b' all the rows with id '1' should have the value true within a new column.

**What I got:**

```
+---------+-----------+
|    id   |    value  |
+---------------------+
|    1    |     A     |
|    1    |     A     |
|    1    |     B     |
|    2    |     C     |
|    2    |     A     |
|    3    |     B     |
|    4    |     C     |
|    5    |     A     |
+---------+-----------+
```

**What I want:**

```
+---------+-----------+
|    id   |Contains_B |
+---------------------+
|    1    |   True    |
|    1    |   True    |
|    1    |   True    |
|    2    |   False   |
|    2    |   False   |
|    3    |   True    |
|    4    |   False   |
|    5    |   False   |
+---------+-----------+
```

**Logic:**
If at least one row with the same *id* contains a B, set the column *Contains_B* for all there *id's* to True, else to false.

**What I tried:**

```
df[“Contains_B”] = df[“id”].apply(lambda x: idContainsB(df, x))
def idContainsB(df, id):
    df_for_id = df[df[“id”] == id] #select data for specific id
    is_in = “B” in df_for_id[“value”].values #evaluate if column contains b
    return is_in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare value `B` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) first and then test if at least one `True` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
df['Contains_B'] = df['value'].eq('B').groupby(df['id']).transform('any')
```

Or get all `id` with `B` and then for new column use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['Contains_B'] = df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['value'].eq('B'), 'id'])
print (df)
   id value  Contains_B
0   1     A        True
1   1     A        True
2   1     B        True
3   2     C       False
4   2     A       False
5   3     B        True
6   4     C       False
7   5     A       False
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using regex:

```
### Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5],
    'value':['A','A','B','C','A','B','C','A']
})


### Create pattern
p = r'[B]'

### Filter DataFrame
df['contains_B'] = df['id'].isin(set(df[df['value'].str.contains(p)]['id']))

### Output
print(df)
   id value  contains_B
0   1     A        True
1   1     A        True
2   1     B        True
3   2     C       False
4   2     A       False
5   3     B        True
6   4     C       False
7   5     A       False
```